# regex extract text pdf

Tags: python, regex

Going crazy trying to need a number ID from each person in a pdf file.

The situation: in a pdf file, have a lot of people that received some money. i have to extract which ones received x money in a specific date.

i used `cpf` id that looks like: 000.000.000-00

CPF is an identification document that has an unique number for each brazilian person.

The code is ok but when the name of person have more than 5 names, the ID called by CPF break a line, being like:

234.234.234-

23

and the ones who have their CPF's in this \n, cant be found because the regex don't cover it. i tried everything n nothing works.

I'm using this code in `regex: r"\d{3}[\.]\d{3}[\.]\d{3}[-](\s?\d{0,2})"`

Edit 1:

I realized that the problem wasn't in the regex but its in the text format received from the function.

The text are being collected like: ' 00,0 Benefício Saldo Conta Aldair Souza Lima) 143.230.234- Valor Mobilidade 12 '

The last 2 digits of `cpf` are showing up in the end of the text string. I looked and debugged the code and seems like the line break in the PDF is causing all this trouble.

I changed the regex to find people by name but there's no name pattern cause they are so different.

I'm thinking in some way that i can make a regex to `match: \d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[-]`

than after N caracthers i match:

`'\s\d\s'` (' 12 ' from the example) cause the last 2 digits always have this 2 blank espaces, one before and one after.

Is there some way that I can do it? Help me guys plz

Answer (score 2):

Specific to your `00,0 Benefício Saldo Conta Aldair Souza Lima) 143.230.234- Valor Mobilidade 12` example:

`(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-)[^\d]*?(\d{2})`

It first matches and captures the `000.000.000-` part: `(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-)`

Then matches but does not capture anything that's not digits: `[^\d]*?`

Then matches and captures two more digits: `(\d{2})`

Not the best implementation, since the results are returned in two separate groups, but hope this helps.

Comment: You can write `[^\d]*?` as `\D*`

Answer (score 0):

You keep replacing the question thus delete the helpful comments. Many good suggestions should have worked by now, but you are not supplying a true minimal sample of input and output. thus the best comments so far should have got you past

`((\d{3}\.)+\d{3}-)\D*(\d{2})\b` https://regexr.com/6sb3q

[image]

Comment: i have an issue with the other question sry

Comment: this example show up my situation but i need to filter up this second match, get it? i used the comments that u guys gave me before but didnt work at all